# What do you call a specific time "interval" in a chart?

Tags: plot, graph, charts

In the example chart below, there's a **time interval** of 2 months between ticks along the x-axis. Is there a certain term for a particular time window represented by two consecutive ticks in the chart? For example, Feb '22 - Apr '22. I suppose saying "time window" or "time frame" works, but I'm just curious if there's a more appropriate term. Also, "time frame" is more ambiguous because it could span any amount of time. But I'd like to specifically refer to a time frame that spans one time interval.

[image]

Thanks in advance